# Documenting Cypress.io tests with JSDoc

Tags: documentation, cypress, e2e-testing, jsdoc

Is there a way to document Cypress spec files with JSDoc? It doesn't seem to catch the *describe()* and *it()* hooks. I've found [this](https://medium.com/@averment/how-to-document-cucumber-js-hooks-step-definitions-with-jsdoc-a48c7ecbce46) article that describes a workaround for cucumber.js, but it doesn't seem to work for me.